# Gibt es eine deutsche Übersetzung zu „friend zone“?

Tags: english-to-german, single-word-request

Ich habe zumindest „Freundeszone“ ([erste Google-Treffer](https://www.google.com/search?q=friend+zone+deutsch)) noch nie gehört.

Ein [Wikipediaeintrag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friend_zone) existiert für Englisch, Spanisch, Portugiesisch und Russisch.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ich hatte den Begriff überhaupt noch nicht gehört. Soweit ich den Wikipedia-Artikel verstehe, ist er im englischen Sprachraum (oder nur in den USA?) durch eine Comedyserie verbreitet worden. Vielleicht hat sich der Ausdruck, den die deutsche Synchronfassung verwendet hat, zumindest unter Fans der Serie verbreitet, vielleicht hat er im deutschen Sprachraum aber auch gar keine Resonanz gefunden.

Wenn ich ein Wort bilden müßte, würde es wahrscheinlich eher etwas mit *Freundschafts-* als mit *Freundes-* werden. Näherliegend ist aber eine weniger wörtliche Wiedergabe mit *einseitiger*, *nicht erwiderter* oder *unerfüllter Liebe*.

---

In [einer Diskussion im dict.cc-Forum](http://www.dict.cc/forum-questions/detail-703534-friend-zone.html) wird für *to be in the friend zone* u.a. die Übersetzung *in der Freundschaftsfalle stecken* vorgeschlagen. Das finde ich gelungen, und es wird im Web auch verwendet.

Comment: *Freundschaftsfalle* gefällt mir. Das sollte der Kern der Antwort sein, im Moment wirkt es eher wie eine Randnotiz. +1 anyways; good catch.

Answer (score -1):

Eine direktere Übersetzung als die „Freundschaftsfalle“ wäre offenbar „Freundschaftszone“, und auch dafür findet man Belege im Netz.

Nachtrag, der nichts zur Frage beiträgt: Zur Bedeutung der “boyfriend zone” siehe die erste Episode von “Coupling”.